# how to generate unique weekid using weekofyear in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table I"m just iterating dates of 50 years.

Using the values of weekofyear("date") -> week_no_in_this_year.

I would like to create a column using (week_no_in_this_year), it should be unique for a week. name it as -> week_id

which should be concatination of Year+two_digit_week_no_in_this_year+Some_number(to make this id unique for one week). I tried like below:

> concat(concat(YEAR,IF(week_no_in_this_year<10,
>   concat(0,week_no_in_this_year),week_no_in_this_year)),'2') AS week_id.

But I'm facing issue for few dates for below scenario's:

```
SELECT weekofyear("2019-01-01") ;
SELECT concat(concat("2019",IF(1<10, concat(0,1),1)),'2') AS week_id;
Expected Result: 2019012

SELECT weekofyear("2019-12-31");
SELECT concat(concat("2019",IF(1<10, concat(0,1),1)),'2') AS week_id;
Expected Result: 2020012
```

Comment: I would like to simplify my question with small changes, with below examples -

In hive How to find the year from weekofyear(date) result? 
> Ex1: "2019-01-01" belongs to week 1 of 2019, 
> Ex2: "2019-12-30" belongs to week 1 of 2020.

So that I will create a column by combing both the results.
Result required for the above scenario(Examples)-

    Ex1: 201901
    Ex2: 202001.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: @jeevankishore You cant get year from weekofyear. Weekofyear is just a number ranging 1 - 53. Why not use year(date)?

Comment: @Bala: I aware that there is no such predefined method to get year out of weekofyear.So, I tried for any work around possible. 2) year(date) won't give expected result, if you clearly go through my question.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario only happens when there is a split between years at the end of a given year (that is Dec 31) and the week number is rollover to next year.  If we put a condition for this case, then we get what you expect.

> Right function is the same as substr (, -n).

```
SELECT DTE as Date, 
 CONCAT(IF(MONTH(DTE)=12 and WEEKOFYEAR(DTE)=1, year(DTE)+1, year(DTE)), 
           SUBSTR(CONCAT('0', WEEKOFYEAR(DTE)), -2), '2') as weekid 
FROM tbl;

Result:
Date            WeekId
2019-01-01      2019012
2019-11-01      2019442
2019-12-31      2020012
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but  issue wasn't resolved Eg: For 2019-12-31, 2019-01-01 dates the result still - 2019012

Comment: i updated my answer to handle end of the year. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with UDF.  Create a python script and push it to HDFS

mypy.py

```
import sys
import datetime

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()
  (y,m,d) = line.split("-")
  d = datetime.date(int(y),int(m),int(d)).isocalendar()
  print str(d[0])+str(d[1])
```

In Hive

```
add file hdfs:/user/cloudera/mypy.py;

select transform("2019-1-1") using "python mypy.py" as (week_id);
INFO  : OK
+----------+--+
| week_id  |
+----------+--+
| 20191    |
+----------+--+

select transform("2019-12-30") using "python mypy.py" as (week_id)
+----------+--+
| week_id  |
+----------+--+
| 20201    |
+----------+--+
1 row selected (33.413 seconds)
```

Comment: I would like to clarify you my exact question, In hive How to find the year from weekofyear(date) result? 
Ex1: "2019-01-01" belongs to week 1 of 2019, 
Ex2: "2019-12-30" belongs to week 1 of 2020.

So that I will create a column by combing both the results.
Result required for the above scenario(Examples)-
Ex1: 201901
Ex2: 202001.

Comment: Thanks Bala, for your answer. But, I'm generating calendar data not querying the existing table. I can't use udf while generating the calendar table.

Comment: I'm planning to try a case statement when the month =12 & weekofyear=1 increment year +1 else year.